# Unity - passing variables from different scripts + making enemies flee

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, unityscript

Ive seen a few questions similar to mine but I can't get it working for my particular need.

I have 2 scripts both in unityscript, EnemyHealth.js and BasicAI.js . In EnemyHealth.js I have an int variable called Health. I want to pass this over as a variable within BasicAI.js so that I can check whether the enemies health is below a certain range. Both scripts are attached to a game object 'Enemy'.

The second part of my question is, if var Health is below a certain amount (say, 20) I want a function flee() to be called. How would I make the enemy turn away from the player and proceed to move away ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, you'd want to use (GetComponent)[http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html]. What this does is lets you get other scripts on a GameObject of a particular type. In your case, you'd be doing something like:

```
var enemyHealth = gameObject.GetComponent(EnemyHealth);
```

Then you'd just need a public way to access the variable called Health, whether that variable is public or there is some sort of getter that is public (if you don't want BasicAI altering health, then you'd want to go the getter route instead of just making the variable public).

Now, as to make the enemy flee, that's a pretty complicated question that involves a number of things and I think it might be a bit too broad to answer in general. Might want to look up some basic AI scripting to get a handle on those concepts.

Answer (score 0):

There is various ways to call another script in Unity. Either GetComponent as Brett said but I would use FindObjectsOfType (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) in your case.

The AI question is pretty unclear. Do you already have a AI that does something? Just to call the flee method just type what you said in your question (probably in Update(http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html).

```
if(Health < 20){
  flee();
}
```